# not create fsave file in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

No file is created when the function is called.
Where is the error in the code ?

```
public static void Save()
{
    SaveLoad.Records.Add(Record.Current);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Records.bin");
    bf.Serialize(file, SaveLoad.Records);
    file.Close();
//Test not create file too
FileStream file2 = File.Create(@"D:\Unity\PACMAN\test.txt");
    bf.Serialize(file2, "Testing");
    file2.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mistake, it was elsewhere.
Here is the new function.

```
public static void Save()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Records.bin");
    bf.Serialize(file, SaveLoad.Records);
    file.Close();
}
```